# Is $\log(n!) \in\Theta(n \log n)$

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, asymptotics

Is $\log(n!) \in\Theta(n \log n)$?

I know it is $O(n \log n)$ because $\log(n!) \leq \log(n^n)$ which is the same as $\log(n!) \leq n \log n$.

But how can I show it is also $\Omega(n \log n)$?

Comment: Stirling, say. $ $

Comment: Note that $\log(n!)$ can be split into a sum. This sum is a Riemann approximation of some integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from Stirling's formula, but you can also give a very elementary proof.  Note that the $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ largest factors in $n!$ are all at least $n/2$, so $n!\geq (n/2)^{n/2-1}$.  So $$\log(n!)\geq \left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)\log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}n\log n-\frac{\log{2}}{2}n-\log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right).$$

For $n$ large, $\log 2/2\ll\log n/2$ and $\log(n/2)\ll n\log n$, so we get $\log(n!)\geq Cn\log n$ for any $C<1/2$ for sufficiently large $n$.

In fact, you can replace all the $2$s in the above argument with any $k>1$, and obtain that $\log(n!)$ is eventually greater than $Cn\log n$ for any $C<1/k$.  Letting $k$ approach $1$, you can conclude that in fact $\log(n!)\sim n\log n$.

Comment: "For $n$ large, $\log 2/2\ll\log n/2$ and $\log(n/2)\ll n\log n$, so we get $\log(n!)\geq Cn\log n$ for any $C<1/2$ for sufficiently large $n$." Shouldn't it be $n \log 2/2\ll\log n/2$, but then it wouldn't be true. I am not able to understand this line and its significance, can you help?

Comment: The first term has a factor of $n$ as well: $\frac{\log 2}{2}\ll\frac{\log n}{2}$ implies $\frac{\log 2}{2}n\ll\frac{1}{2}n\log n$.

Comment: So in a way $n log n$ will dominate and thus $\log(n!)\geq \frac12 nlog  n$?

Comment: Well, you don't quite get that $\log(n!)\geq\frac{1}{2}n\log n$; you have $\log(n!)\geq\frac{1}{2}n\log n-f(n)$ where $f(n)$ is much smaller than $\frac{1}{2}n\log n$.  In particular, you can say more precisely that for any $\epsilon>0$, $f(n)\leq\epsilon n\log n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, so letting $C=\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon$ you get $\log(n!)\geq Cn\log n$ for sufficiently large $n$ for any $C<1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! First notice that

$$ \log(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^n \log(k). $$

As $\log$ is increasing, you'll get

$$\int_{1}^{n+1} \log(t)\mathrm{d}t \geqslant \sum_{k=1}^n \log(k) \geqslant \int_{2}^{n} \log(t)\mathrm{d}t. $$

For $\int_{1}^{x} \log(t)\mathrm{d}t = x\log(x)-x$, you actually have the even better estimate $\log(n!) \sim n\log(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\log(x)$ is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) gives:
$$ \int_{1}^{n+1}\log(x)\,dx \geq \frac{\log(n+1)}{2}+\log(n!) \tag{1}$$
from which $\log(n!)=O(n\log n)$, as well as:
$$   \log(n!)\geq\int_{1/2}^{n+1/2}\log(x)\,dx \tag{2} $$
from which $\log(n!)=\Omega(n\log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ if and only if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) / g(n) > 0$ ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_definition)).

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log n!}{n \log n} = 1$$

Therefore the answer is **yes**.