# Factorial and $\Theta$ notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

If $N$ is a $n$-bit number, how many bits longs is $N!$, approximately in $\Theta( )$ form?

I know that 
$$
\log(N!) = \log(N*(N-1)*...*2*1) \leq \log (N)+\log (N-1)+...+\log(2)+\log(1)
$$
$$
\log(N!) = O(N\log(N))
$$
I'm unsure about how to show it in terms of $\Theta$ instead of O notation

Comment: It is indeed $\Theta(n\log n)$, and even $(1+o(1)) n\log n$. See e.g. [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489770/proving-asymptotic-barrier-o-notation?lq=1), [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608565/is-logn-in-thetan-log-n?lq=1), or [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376988/limit-of-frac-lognn-logn-as-n-to-infty).